# .htaccess, use mod_rewrite to rewrite to a file OUTSIDE the web root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is a representation of my directory structure:

```
/var/www
  /html/site
    .htaccess
  /secret
    file.php
```

I'd like to use the `.htaccess` file to rewrite url requests made to `http://example.com/files/1234` to the code `file.php` sitting outside of the webroot. This is for security reasons, the other developers I'm working with are insistent that this code sit outside of web accessible directories. So far, my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ ../../secret/file.php?file_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

But I'm getting a **400 Bad Request** when I try to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. The webserver can't directly access files outside of the document root. If you think about it, there would be quite a security problem if it could. What you can do is rewrite to a file within the document root that includes or reads from the file that is located outside of the root. (Moved from comments...)

Comment: If there are no better answers in a few days, I'll accept this one.

Comment: how much is a few days for you??

Comment: Maybe he meant years ;)

Comment: Wow, looks like this one got away from me! Sorry it took so long, but here you go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access files located outside document-root using .htaccess.

**But** you can do that by adding an alias to your apache config file, like that:

```
Alias /secret/ /home/site_name/web/yoursite.com/secret/
```